# How is it possible for a human eye to see the entire reticle in a reflector sight?

Tags: optics, vision

[image][Reflector sights](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflector_sight) such as used on fighter planes project an image of a [reticle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reticle) "focused at infinity", that is, whose rays are parallel, onto a semi transparent window. How is it possible for a human eye to see the image of the whole reticle, when the reticle is bigger than the human eye itself (typically the size of the sight window, around 10 centimeters across)? If the rays are parallel then only a part of the reticle, the size of retina should be visible

Comment: You might as well ask how it's possible to see *anything* larger than our retina.

Comment: No, the light reflected off of almost all objects is not collimated

Comment: You can see constellations that are about a billion trillion times bigger than your retina or pupils, and which are probably a much better approximation of a source at infinity than anything projected with a reflector, though.

Comment: Okay, but given the ratio of diameter of the object and the distance from the object to the retina, even when the rays are highly collimated, theres still enough deviation for rays from opposite edges of the object to enter your retina. The reticle is about 10cm across, no more than 50cm away from a pilots face, so its impossible for a small deviation of rays to account for this

Comment: Your diagram only shows rays that emanate from a single point on the reticle. If you want it to show how the pilot can see other points on the reticle, then you need it to trace rays that emanate from those other points. [Hint: The optic will make all of the rays emanating from some other point parallel to each other, but that bundle of rays won't be parallel to the bundle that the diagram already shows.]

Comment: @SolomonSlow That looks like an answer

Comment: @BioPhysicist, I'd write an answer if I could find the time and the tools to make a decent illustration.